# How to render parsed JSON response in Flutter App

Tags: flutter

I'm pretty new to Flutter and trying to figure out how the below JSON response can be used in my app. Right now, I would only like to display the texts in the list.

This is the JSON response:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "61e13bc871cc944be6736a67",
        "paraOne": [
            "Homeopathy, the longest established alternative medicine to come out of Europe, was created in 1796 by Samuel Hahnemann.",
            "Hahnemann rejected the mainstream medicine of the late 18th century as irrational and inadvisable because it was largely ineffective and often harmful.",
            "He advocated the use of single drugs at lower doses and promoted an immaterial, vitalistic view of how living organisms function.",
            "The term homeopathy was coined by Hahnemann and first appeared in print in 1807.",
            "He also coined the expression allopathic medicine, which was used to pejoratively refer to traditional Western medicine."
        ],
        "paraTwo": [
            "Hahnemann began to test what effects various substances may produce in humans, a procedure later called homeopathic proving.",
            "These tests required subjects to test the effects of ingesting substances by recording all their symptoms as well as the ancillary conditions under which they appeared.",
            "He published a collection of provings in 1805, and a second collection of 65 preparations appeared in his book, Materia Medica Pura (1810)."
        ],
        "paraThree": [
            "As Hahnemann believed that large doses of drugs that caused similar symptoms would only aggravate illness, he advocated for extreme dilutions.",
            "A technique was devised for making dilutions that Hahnemann claimed would preserve the substance's therapeutic properties while removing its harmful effects.",
            "Hahnemann believed that this process enhanced the spirit-like medicinal powers of the crude substances.",
            "He gathered and published an overview of his new medical system in his book, The Organon of the Healing Art (1810), with a sixth edition published in 1921 that homeopaths still use today."
        ],
        "paraFour": [
            "Homeopathy achieved its greatest popularity in the 19th century.",
            "It was introduced to the United States in 1825 with the first homeopathic school opening in 1835.",
            "Throughout the 19th century, dozens of homeopathic institutions appeared in Europe and the United States.",
            "During this period, homeopathy was able to appear relatively successful, as other forms of treatment could be harmful and ineffective.",
            "By the end of the century the practice began to wane, with the last exclusively homeopathic medical school in the US closing in 1920."
        ],
        "paraFive": [
            "In the 1970s, homeopathy made a significant comeback, with sales of some homeopathic products increasing tenfold.",
            "The trend corresponded with the rise of the New Age movement, and may be in part due to an irrational preference for natural products, and the longer consultation times homeopathic practitioners provided."
        ]
    }
]
```

The JSON model class(This has been autogenerated from one of those JSON to Dart parser websites)

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<History> userFromJson(String str) => List<History>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => History.fromJson(x)));

String userToJson(List<History> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class History {
  String? id;
  List<String>? paraOne;
  List<String>? paraTwo;
  List<String>? paraThree;
  List<String>? paraFour;
  List<String>? paraFive;

  History({this.id, this.paraOne, this.paraTwo, this.paraThree, this.paraFour, this.paraFive});

  History.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    this.id = json["_id"];
    this.paraOne = json["paraOne"]==null ? null : List<String>.from(json["paraOne"]);
    this.paraTwo = json["paraTwo"]==null ? null : List<String>.from(json["paraTwo"]);
    this.paraThree = json["paraThree"]==null ? null : List<String>.from(json["paraThree"]);
    this.paraFour = json["paraFour"]==null ? null : List<String>.from(json["paraFour"]);
    this.paraFive = json["paraFive"]==null ? null : List<String>.from(json["paraFive"]);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["_id"] = this.id;
    if(this.paraOne != null)
      data["paraOne"] = this.paraOne;
    if(this.paraTwo != null)
      data["paraTwo"] = this.paraTwo;
    if(this.paraThree != null)
      data["paraThree"] = this.paraThree;
    if(this.paraFour != null)
      data["paraFour"] = this.paraFour;
    if(this.paraFive != null)
      data["paraFive"] = this.paraFive;
    return data;
  }
}
```

This is the API call:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import './history_model.dart';

class HistoryProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<dynamic> _data = [];

  List<dynamic> get data {
    return[..._data];
  }

  Future<void> getData() async {
    final url = Uri.http('192.168.0.8:3008', '/history');
    final response = await http.get(url);
    List<History> history = userFromJson(response.body);
    final extractedData = json.decode(response.body);
    print(extractedData);
    _data = history;
    print(_data);
  }
}
```

The widget that I would like the data on:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeScreenState createState() => HomeScreenState();
}

class HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    Provider.of<HistoryProvider>(context, listen: false).getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var history = Provider.of<HistoryProvider>(context).data;
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        title: const Text('Doctor App'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(
            //This is where I want the data on every Text Widget.
          ),
          itemCount: history.length
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Also, If I just want one paragraph i.e `paraOne` what to do in that case?

Answer (score 0):

First you also need to specify `itemCount: X`. Then because the builder receives a function with context and index as parameters, simply use `myList[index]`.

**Tip:** Many classes in Flutter have lots of parameters your best friend here is the IDE/Editor. Learn what key combination shows the parameters of a constructor/function and use it especially at the beggining. In intellij for example it's **CTRL+P**. This will help you spot important parameters and learn Flutter better.

```dart
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeScreenState createState() => HomeScreenState();
}

class HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    Provider.of<HistoryProvider>(context, listen: false).getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var history = Provider.of<HistoryProvider>(context).data;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        title: const Text('Doctor App'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: history.length, // Add this
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(
            history[index],   // Add this
          ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

For more details have a [look here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/long-lists).

Comment: This doesn't work. I get a message saying instance of History which is the name of the model class. Do you know how I can go inside the class to fetch the values of paraOne, paraTwo etc? Also, you might want to take a look at the code you have written, you have defined the itemCount property twice which is not possible.

Comment: I actually now know what I need to do. Your answer kind of led me to it.

Comment: Wrote it a bit in rush, sorry. I answered just from the perspective of the ListView.builder() , didn't verified that you get the data correctly. Well i'm happy you made it!